# Django - How to apply onlivechange on CharField / IntegerField

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I want to hide the field form.name_of_parent_if_minor if the age (CharField) < 18 else show. I am not getting where to write jQuery or JS code or add separate js file. For this do I need to the html definition and add  tag for age (CharField) or we can perform action on this as well.

I am new to the Django so if you find any mistakes in my code then any help would be appreciated for guidance.

forms.py

```
class StudentDetailsForm(forms.ModelForm):
     class Meta:
         model = StudentDetails
```

views.py

```
class StudentCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    template_name = 'student/student_details_form.html'
    model = StudentDetails
    form_class = StudentDetailsForm
    success_url = "/"
```

html

```
{% extends 'student/base.html' %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}
<div id="idParentAccordian" class="content-section">
    <form method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}

        <div class="card mt-3">
            <div class="card-header">
                <a class="collapsed card-link" style="display: block;" data-toggle="collapse"
                    href="#idPersonalInformation">Personal Information</a>
            </div>
            <div id="idPersonalInformation" class="collapse show" data-parent="#idParentAccordian">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-6">
                            {{ form.joining_date|as_crispy_field }}
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-6">
                            {{ form.class|as_crispy_field }}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    {{ form.student_name|as_crispy_field }}
                    {{ form.father_name|as_crispy_field }}
                    {{ form.mother_name|as_crispy_field }}
                    {{ form.gender|as_crispy_field }}
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-6">
                            {{ form.date_of_birth|as_crispy_field }}
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-6">
                            {{ form.age|as_crispy_field }}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        {{ form.name_of_parent_if_minor|as_crispy_field }}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group mt-3">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Save</button>
            <a class="btn btn-outline-secondary" href="javascript:history.go(-1)">Cancel</a>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the easiest way but not the cleanest is to add JS script in your html

the recommanded way is to add static folder to your app and load static files in your html template using {% load static %}

Comment: I need to pass the entered parameter in the function. In this case how to achieve this since I am using crispy tags.